# Using a SCSS variable (containing a calculation with parentheses) within a calc-function removes these parentheses on compilation

Tags: css, sass

### Problem

When I try avoid repetition of a part in a variable containing a CSS calc-function, I suddenly get different results on compilation due to missing parentheses.

### Example

The following code works as intended (note that the horizontal padding only differs a bit at the end of the calc-function):

```
#output-element-1 {
    padding: 
        0 
        calc((#{$line-height * 1em} + #{$padding-y * 2} + #{$border-height * 2} - #{$icon-size}) / 2 - 1px) 
        0 
        calc((#{$line-height * 1em} + #{$padding-y * 2} + #{$border-height * 2} - #{$icon-size}) / 2 + 1px);
}
```

Which compiles correctly into:

```css
padding: 0 calc((1.5em + 3rem + 2px - 1.25rem) / 2 - 1px) 0 calc((1.5em + 3rem + 2px - 1.25rem) / 2 + 1px);
```

When I try to avoid duplication and isolate a bit of that calc-function into a separate variable, like this:

```
$output-element-padding-x: (#{$line-height * 1em} + #{$padding-y * 2} + #{$border-height * 2} - #{$icon-size}) / 2;

#output-element-2 {
    padding: 
        0 
        calc(#{$output-element-padding-x} - 1px) 
        0 
        calc(#{$output-element-padding-x} + 1px);
}
```

This gets compiles into (note the missing parentheses):

```css
#output-element-2 {
  padding: 0 calc(1.5em + 3rem + 2px - 1.25rem/2 - 1px) 0 calc(1.5em + 3rem + 2px - 1.25rem/2 + 1px);
}
```

Example can also be viewed at: https://codepen.io/brenner/pen/YzXYxrj?editors=1100

### Question

Is there perhaps a way you can force the parentheses to persist correctly through compilation?

Answer (score 0):

Because of the way variables are read, I don't think you can do this. However, this is a really good use case for SASS `@functions`!

```
$line-height: 1.5;
$padding-y: 1.5rem;
$border-height: 1px;
$icon-size: 1.25rem;

@function output-element-padding-x($val: #{'1px'}, $operator: #{'+'}) {
  @return calc( ( #{$line-height * 1em} + #{$padding-y * 2} + #{$border-height * 2} - #{$icon-size} ) / 2 #{$operator} #{$val} );
}

#output-element-2 {
    padding: 
        0 
        output-element-padding-x( 1px, #{'-'} )
        0 
        output-element-padding-x( 1px, #{'+'} )

}
```

I'm using the function to pass two parameters, the value you want to change per function and the operator - plus/minus/divide/multiply - whatever. I also set default values so you can just use `mixin_test()` and it will default to `1px` and `+`

This compiles to:

```
    #output-element-2 {
  padding: 0 calc( ( 1.5em + 3rem + 2px - 1.25rem ) / 2 - 1px ) 0 calc( ( 1.5em + 3rem + 2px - 1.25rem ) / 2 + 1px );
}
```

This will keep your parenthesis as well as the grouping you have set up to make sure the order of operation is correct.